# Calling a stored procedure with varchar as output parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I want to assign the output parameter of a stored procedure to a session variable.So,basically,I am looking to call a stored procedure that has a varchar out parameter.The stored procedure is as follows:

```
    Alter proc spCheckTaskPerformed
    @TaskId int,
    @Email varchar(100),
    @Status varchar(100) output
    as
    begin
    Select @Status = Status from tblTaskPerformed
    where [Email] = @Email and [TaskId]=@TaskId
    end
```

The code that I have is as below:

```
      private void CheckTaskPerformed()
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EasyRozMoney_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCheckTaskPerformed", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskId", lblTaskId.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Session["Email"].ToString());

        SqlParameter outputParameter = new SqlParameter();
        outputParameter.ParameterName = "@Status";
        outputParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
        outputParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(outputParameter);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string Status = outputParameter.Value.ToString();
        lblStatus.Text = "This task has " + Status;
    }
}
```

But i get an error message - String[2]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0. at the below line.

```
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Yes, you have to set the `Size` property to `100` on the C# side also.

Comment: outputParameter.Size = 100;

Answer (score 0):

You must send a value into status or specify null input:

```
 @Status varchar(100) = null output
```